# Intuition for a 2-Monotone Boolean Function

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am currently studying Chapter 8 of [Krama and Hammer's textbook on Boolean Functions](https://doc.lagout.org/science/0_Computer%20Science/2_Algorithms/Boolean%20Functions_%20Theory%2C%20Algorithms%2C%20and%20Applications%20%5BCrama%20%26%20Hammer%202011-05-16%5D.pdf), and having a hard time understanding what it means for a function to be "k-monotone."

I am currently working off the following definition of "K-monotone" in Chapter 8:

> A Boolean function $f$ on $\mathcal{B}^n$ is $k$-monotone ($1 ≤ k \leq n$) if, for all pairs of subsets $S,T \subseteq \{1,2,...,n\}$ such that $|S \cup T| ≤ k$, $S$ and $T$ are comparable with respect to $f$

**I am wondering if someone has a more intuitive definition for what it means for a function to be "2-monotone"?** I am specifically interested in this "2-monotone" rather than "k-monotone" since "2-monotone" seems to be used by a number of works that study linear threshold gates.

I think that part of my confusion arises from the fact that I think about monotonicity as a property that's related to its input-output relationship rather than the "comparability" of its inputs. For example, I think about a positive Boolean function as a function $f$ that is positive in all its input variables where a function is positive in $x_1$ means that  $f(0,x_2,...,x_n) \leq f(1,x_2,...,x_n)$ for all values of $x_2,...x_n$.

Comment: What does it mean for $S$ and $T$ to be *comparable with respect to $f$*?